Dynamically change active storage service on rails model?
I'm using active storage with s3 to attach a file to a model called Document. I need to add support for users in the EU that want their document files stored in an s3 bucket in the EU.
I have my storage.yml configured like:
amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY_ACCESS'] %>
    region: <%= ENV['S3_REGION_EU'] %>
    bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] %>

amazon_eu:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY_ACCESS'] %>
    region: <%= ENV['S3_REGION_EU'] %>
    bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME_EU'] %>

Is there a way to dynamically switch in the service in the Document model based on the region set in the Account? Something like:
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  
  if account.region == 'eu'
    has_one_attached :file, service: amazon_eu
  else
    has_one_attached :file, service: amazon
  end

end

Or really anyway to specify the specific service that I want to use dynamically at runtime?

I figured out how to do it. I created a custom service for active storage that inherits from the s3 service and created a second bucket instance on the class for the eu region I want to use.
# lib/active_storage/service/dynamic_storage_service.rb
require "active_storage/service/s3_service"

module ActiveStorage
  class Service::DynamicStorageService < ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service
    # create attributes for another client and bucket
    attr_reader :client_eu, :bucket_eu
    

    # override the initializer with options to pass in an eu bucket from the storage.yml
    # this is where you would create whatever extra buckets you need
    def initialize(bucket:, bucket_eu:, upload: {}, public: false, **options)
      eu_options = options.except(:region)
      eu_options[:region] = eu_options[:region_eu]

      @client_eu = Aws::S3::Resource.new(eu_options.except(:region_eu))
      @bucket_eu = @client_eu.bucket(bucket_eu)

      super(bucket: bucket, upload: upload, public: public, **options.except(:region_eu))
    end

    private
      # override the method where the bucket is used
      # this is where you would add whatever logic you need to select the bucket
      # this is the implementation that works for me
      # the method just needs to return the S3 object and everything else will work
      def object_for(key)
        # this is how you get the record based on the key
        document_id = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find_by(blob_id: ActiveStorage::Blob.find_by(key: key).id).record_id

        document = Document.find(document_id)

        if document.account.region == 'eu'
          return bucket_eu.object(key)
        else
          return bucket.object(key)
        end
      end
  end
end

And then you would use it in the storage.yml instead of the regular S3 service:
# config/storage.yml
amazon:
    service: DynamicStorage
    access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY_ACCESS'] %>
    region: <%= ENV['S3_REGION'] %>
    bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] %>
    region_eu: <%= ENV['S3_REGION_EU'] %>
    bucket_eu: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME_EU'] %>

And the Document.rb can work like normal
# document.rb
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  
  has_one_attached :file

end

You could probably rewrite this better and make it more dynamic and able to handle as many buckets as you want but this is what worked for me

Overriding a private method in a class of the framework and adding a dependency to your Document model seems like a terrible idea. What if that Rails class changes in the next version? Or what if you want to add files to other models in your application?

It's an entirely new class so I can just add another config to storage.yml that uses the regular s3 service if I need another model to have attached files (I already do this as the account has a logo attached). And active storage already lets you specify which service config you want to use on a model by model basis. It's not ideal but I can't think of a better way to do it

I could've also just wrote an entirely new service object that didn't inherit from the S3Service class so I wouldn't have to worry about compatibility but frankly I think that's just overkill. The odds of Rails pushing a change that would break this anytime soon is extremely low

This might not be the exact solution you're looking for but you might want to consider using single table inheritance and defining a separate class:
class EUDocument < Document
  belongs_to :account
  has_one_attached :file, service: :amazon_eu
end

ActiveStorage is built around a class level macro and doesn't really have any documented features for instance level reconfiguration.
While you could do crazy hacks like using class_eval or stubbing over the instance methods generated by the macro it's going to be very brittle.
If this is a dealbreaker you might want to consider using the S3 gem directly to implement the feature as ActiveStorage is a very opinionated design that at the same time tries to be hyper flexible.

Alternatively if your EU traffic is going through other servers you could use an ENV var to configure the region per server.
